# How to test if a list of ids exist in another list of ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a where clause on MySql. I have a column in DB that have a list of ids separated by comma (2,5,6,8). And I need to test if each of those ids is in another list of ids. If I had just one id to test (not a list), I know how to do with a “where IN” clause. So, how to test if a list of ids exist in another list of ids?

Comment: Your problem is having a string column with a list of numeric ids.  That is not the right way to store such data.

Comment: It's really hard to iterate through comma-separated values in SQL. If you really have to use that format, you probably need to write a stored procedure with a loop.

Comment: See the `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

Comment: Do you have access to change your database design? This is a trivial problem if the data is stored properly.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, I thought that was a ready function for that. I am new on SQL. But as it is not possible to make the list test directly, I will use another table that storage both the ids separatelly to make the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "list of ids" in SQL. What you have is a string, which happens to contain numeric digits and commas.

Storing a list of id's as a string is okay, if you only need to use it like a string. But if you need to do queries that treat the list as a set of discrete id values, you should normalize the data by storing one id per row in a dependent table.

```
CREATE TABLE IdSets (
  entity_id INT NOT NULL,
  item_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (entity_id, item_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES entities(entity_id)
);
```

Then you can solve your problem with a `JOIN` query.

```
SELECT i.entity_id
FROM IdSets AS i LEFT OUTER JOIN TestSets AS t USING (item_id)
GROUP BY entity_id
HAVING COUNT(i.item_id) = COUNT(t.item_id)
```

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why this is answer is not correct.

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: The solution is to normalize the data.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have that luxury, you're stuck with an existing database schema.

Comment: You know about the `FIND_IN_SET()` function, right? While it's not optimal, it does allow searching comma-separated strings.

Comment: Can you explain how to use `FIND_IN_SET()` to compare a list against another list? I believe it works only to find one item in a list, not to find an intersection of lists.

Comment: It's not clear that "the other list" is also a comma-separated string. If it's hard-coded or generated dynamically from a script, you can use `FIND_IN_SET('2', column) AND FIND_IN_SET('3', column) AND ...`

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, I thought that was a ready function for that. I am new on SQL. But as it is not possible to make the list test directly, I will use another table that storage both the ids separatelly to make the test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the tips, I thought that was a ready function for that. I am new on SQL. But as it is not possible to make the list test directly, I will use another table that storage both the ids separatelly to make the test.